# FaultException error on webservice call

Tags: c#, wcf, faultexception

I created a webservice that returnes some categories from database. If i test with the client that WCF is offering everything is perfect.
I started building a client. I added a service reference to my service `http://localhost/Transaction/transaction.svc`. I create a new instance of the client webservice

```
  TransactionClient tc = new TransactionClient("BasicHttpEndpoint");
 Category[] availableCategories = tc.GetAllCategories();
```

I get `Object reference not set to an instance of an object` on the second line of code. The endpoint name is correct.

Any idea why the error ?

PS : if you need more code please let me know what to post.
Thanks in advance.

Edit :

```
  [OperationContract]
  List<Category> GetAllCategories();

  Implementation : 
  public List<Category> GetAllCategories()
   { return db.GetAllCategories()}
```

The service is working is i test with WCFClient, so the rest of my code must be corect.

This is the code that gets me the items from database. I try with the solution posted but the app did not stop.

```
List<Category> response = new List<Category>();
            connect();

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select id_category, name from tbl_category", conn);
            try
            {
                dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                while (dr.Read())
                {
                    Category new_category = new Category();
                    new_category.id_category = int.Parse(dr["id_category"].ToString());
                    new_category.name = dr["name"].ToString();
                    response.Add(new_category);
                }

            }
            catch (SqlException ex)
            {
                Console.Out.Write(ex.ToString());
            }
            finally
            {
                dr.Close();
                conn.Close();
            }

            return response;
```

Comment: It's definitely not on line 2, but inside the call to `GetAllCategories();` You'll need to post that code....

Comment: post the exception message and stack trace too please.

Comment: When is the 'db' instantiated?

Comment: Fault is thrown at the server, so I think the db instance is null.

Comment: Try it again with the test client. Maybe DBA has changed since then.

Comment: database did not change. i tried with the wcf client and with my client and doesn't wanna work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`FaultException` is exception transfered from other side of WCF channel. Meaning, that exception did not happen on line you call `tc.GetAllCategories();`, but on server side, in processing of that method.

`FaultException` wraps exception which occurred on server side. From what we can see in what you pasted, it's `NullReferenceException`. To find exact place where it occurs, set breakpoint in `GetAllCategories` method and step through it until it fails. Since this is a WCF service, exception in handling method call does not crash the service, but wraps the exception and sends it back to client.

Another way to find where error occurs would be to debug service, open Debug -> Exceptions in Visual Studio and tick check box in Thrown column next to *Common Language Runtime Exceptions*. This tells VS debugger to stop execution when error occurs, even though exception will be caught by WCF.

Comment: nothing new. I posted the db code. no error on the output tab.

Comment: Something is `null` for sure in your server side code. How are you hosting the service? Did you try debugging the service process and setting up Exception interception as I described in the answer? Candidates for `null` value are e.g.: `dr["id_category"]` and `dr["name"]`. Check if they are not set by like this: `if (dr["id_category"] != DBNull.Value) handle(); else value_not_set();`.